# X and Y is NaN when using JSON - D3 Layout Pack

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to use a D3 Layout Pack to make some kind of bubble chart. However, if I try to implement it I get that my X and Y is NaN.

Here is a JSfiddle of my work.

https://jsfiddle.net/xkd5uw28/

As you can see in the console I get error `<g> attribute transform: Expected number, "translate(NaN, NaN)"`. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I've been following [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/24y0qL5e/). I even tried to console.log that data and compared it to my data. I don't get r, x or y while the other got it.

Answer (score 0):

If you check out the [API docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Pack-Layout.md#children) it states:

> The children accessor is first invoked for root node in the hierarchy

It also sits alongside some sample data

```
{
 "name": "flare",
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "analytics",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "cluster",
     "children": [
      {"name": "AgglomerativeCluster", "size": 3938},
      {"name": "CommunityStructure", "size": 3812},
      {"name": "MergeEdge", "size": 743}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "graph",
     "children": [
      {"name": "BetweennessCentrality", "size": 3534},
      {"name": "LinkDistance", "size": 5731}
     ]
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

Data provides to the pack layout needs to be in this hierarchical form. If we look at your example however you're providing an array of data, and none of the items within there have a `children` property. You'll need to modify the shape of your data to use this layout.

```
const newData = [
                {
                "adjective": 
                    {
                        "en": "warm",
                        "sv": "varm"}
                },
                {
                    "adjective": 
                    {
                        "en": "clear",
                        "sv": "tydlig"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "adjective": 
                    {
                        "en": "creative",
                        "sv": "kreativ"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "adjective": 
                    {
                        "en": "responsible",
                        "sv": "ansvarstagande"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "adjective": 
                    {
                        "en": "social",
                        "sv": "social"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "adjective": 
                    {
                        "en": "calm",
                        "sv": "lugn"
                    }
        }
];
```